# Design question about useContext in react hooks: similar components but with different context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `Chart` component that consists of `Cell` components. Both the `Chart` and the `Cells` use `useContext` hooks and I provide that context in an outer layer. I want to create a new chart that is similar, but uses a different context. For instance, the original chart stores and looks up information based on keys that are different: when I populate the original context it looks like: `{'player 1': [], 'player 2': [], 'player 3' ...}`, but the new context will look like: `{'You': [], 'Your opponent': []}`

Should I pass a parameter/flag to the `Chart` component that tells it what context to use? And then I could do something like: `const [selectedCombos, handleSelectedDispatch] = usePlayers ? useContext(OriginalContext) : useContext(OtherContext)`

Can I even do something like that? I know it smells bad, but the only alternative I see is copying the `Chart`/`Cell` components to a new file, changing the context it uses and renaming it. That also sucks. What is the right approach here?

I've tried simply copying the code to a new component and using a different context, but that stinks too.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a flag is kind of bad because what if you think in the future, what happens if the `Cell` can use 3 different context? Or more?

Ternary will be bad. And you will be importing context that won't be used.

What you can do is pass a prop with the context.

e.g.

```
// File that render the cell.
import OnlyTheContextYouNeed from '../mycontext/OnlyTheContextYouNeed'

...
    <Cell usedContext={OnlyTheContextYouNeed } />
...

//Cell.jsx    
...
const [selectedCombos, handleSelectedDispatch] = useContext(props.usedContext)
```

This way you don't have to import all the contexts you have in `Cell` and you only import the context you will need and use when you render `Cell`.